# Android Custom applications OTA installation

Tags: android, installation, apk, ota

I would like to find out if it is possible to install applications Over The Air in Android by downloading the apk from a web link.
The application is meant to be customised for each user hence there won't be one application which I could put in the AppStore, but one per user.

There seem to be a post or two on the subject but no clear answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible if the user has enabled the option to download apps from "unknown sources". Of course, you should consider the possibility of including some way of dynamically changing the app to suit the user, and use a single apk. If you elaborate on your problem, there might be suggestions for solutions in SO.

Comment: For security reasons, some unique code is dynamically created for each user. This with other means makes the application safer to use for sensitive operations.